# Is this subscription billing mail from Apple genuine?

Tags: email

Hello I purchased something on June 15 2021 7:27 AM I got email from apple they saying I purchased bike race free bike race plus 1 week help me

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an email. Make sure it's not a phishing attack (a fake email scam trying to trick you) On your iPhone go to Settings -> Apple ID -> Subscriptions and see if you even see this Bike Race Free Style Games in your list of active or expired subscriptions.

Hover over the links on this email and make sure they are going to apple.com and not some other place.

This could be scammers trying to obtain your Apple ID/PW and Credit Card Details.  Beware.

Call Apple Support directly:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232

If it's not a scam then someone using your Apple ID/PW such as a family member may have made an in-app-purchase within the game. It's possible someone compromised your Apple ID/PW. Or a minor child made the purchase and you need to setup family accounts and restrictions so children cannot make purchases without your approval.

The error indicates that either you do not have a credit card on file or the card you have on file with Apple is expired.  But again, it could be scammers trying to fool you into providing them your credit card details so do not click any of those links in the email.

Comment: I'm agreeing with this, I think it's a phishing scam.

You can go to Settings -> iCloud -> Subscriptions to see what subscriptions you are signed up for.

Comment: This looks very much like a scam. Two reasons: they put a comma behind a name, this is a grammar mistake Apple most likely will not make. The email looks different to my AppleStore mails for subscriptions.